# Capistrano changes Rails.root path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

Rails 3.2
ruby 1.9.3

that's where my releases are stored on server

```
deploy@production-web:/var/www/mrd_production/releases$ ls
20150729224354  20150730101637  20150730110152  20150730122336
```

that's where my current productions are stored in server

```
deploy@production-web:/var/www/mrd_production/current$ ls
app                     config.ru  Gemfile       public    spec
assets_manifest_backup  db         Gemfile.lock  Rakefile  tmp
bin                     doc        Guardfile     README    Vagrantfile
Capfile                 features   lib           REVISION
config                  fixtures   log           script
```

So, I am using capistrano for deploy:

```
bundle exec cap production deploy
```

**deploy.rb**

```
lock '3.4.0'

set :application, 's2yd'

set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:mrdelivery/mxad-mr.-delivery.git'

set :keep_releases, 3
set :log_level, :info
set :linked_files, %w{.env}
set :linked_dirs, %w{public/system}
set :migration_role, :app
set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '1.9.3-p484'

namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 3 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart
end

    namespace :rails do
      desc 'Open the rails console on the primary remote server'
      task :console do
        on roles(:app), primary: true do |host|
          command = "cd #{deploy_to}/current && /home/#{host.user}/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec rails console #{fetch(:stage)}"
          exec "ssh -l #{host.user} #{host.hostname} -p #{host.port || 22} -t 'cd #{deploy_to}/current && #{command}'"
        end
      end
    end
```

**config/deploy/production.rb**

```
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/mrd_production' # Change this to match your deploy_dir in vars/app.yml

server '104.130.31.250', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app}

namespace :deploy do
  desc 'generate_ymls'
  task :generate_ymls do
    on roles(:app) do
      upload! File.expand_path('../../database.yml.production',  __FILE__), "#{release_path}/config/database.yml"
    end
  end
end
before "deploy:migrate", 'deploy:generate_ymls'
```

After deploy, I enter the folder `/var/www/mrd_production/current` where my app resides...

```
deploy@production-web:/var/www/mrd_production/current$ RAILS_ENV=production rails c

irb(main):001:0> Rails.root
=> #<Pathname:/var/www/mrd_production/releases/20150730122336>
irb(main):002:0>
```

The problem is `Rails.root` points to `/var/www/mrd_production/releases/20150730122336` but I need it to be pointed to the folder where I am in `/var/www/mrd_production/current`

How can I change Rails.root?

**EDIT**
**bundle exec cap production deploy** log:

```
INFO [8ba777a3] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/s2yd/ as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [8ba777a3] Finished in 0.269 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO Uploading /tmp/s2yd/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
INFO [867961a0] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/s2yd/git-ssh.sh as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [867961a0] Finished in 0.267 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [6be86a24] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@bitbucket.org:mrdelivery/mxad-mr.-delivery.git as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [6be86a24] Finished in 0.900 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [e6f437c4] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /var/www/mrd_production/shared /var/www/mrd_production/releases as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [e6f437c4] Finished in 0.334 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [37165e60] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /var/www/mrd_production/shared/public/system as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [37165e60] Finished in 0.266 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [3c9b9d10] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /var/www/mrd_production/shared as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [3c9b9d10] Finished in 0.265 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO The repository mirror is at /var/www/mrd_production/repo
INFO [0002d83c] Running /usr/bin/env git remote update as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [0002d83c] Finished in 2.495 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [869b66a7] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /var/www/mrd_production/releases/20150730220743 as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [869b66a7] Finished in 0.271 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [1b9871ea] Running /usr/bin/env git archive master | tar -x -f - -C /var/www/mrd_production/releases/20150730220743 as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [1b9871ea] Finished in 0.528 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [c28030f4] Running /usr/bin/env echo "6ce11b0" >> REVISION as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [c28030f4] Finished in 0.266 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [0af78fb4] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /var/www/mrd_production/releases/20150730220743 as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [0af78fb4] Finished in 0.273 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [86aef2af] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/www/mrd_production/shared/.env /var/www/mrd_production/releases/20150730220743/.env as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [86aef2af] Finished in 0.267 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [80cc46a1] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /var/www/mrd_production/releases/20150730220743/public as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [80cc46a1] Finished in 0.268 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [bbfef99c] Running /usr/bin/env rm -rf /var/www/mrd_production/releases/20150730220743/public/system as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [bbfef99c] Finished in 0.270 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [66f90632] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/www/mrd_production/shared/public/system /var/www/mrd_production/releases/20150730220743/public/system as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [66f90632] Finished in 0.268 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [e63b7bd2] Running ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /var/www/mrd_production/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [e63b7bd2] Finished in 0.701 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [89bd1320] Running ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [89bd1320] Finished in 15.517 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [8e1765be] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /var/www/mrd_production/releases/20150730220743/assets_manifest_backup as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [8e1765be] Finished in 0.266 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [30408583] Running /usr/bin/env cp /var/www/mrd_production/releases/20150730220743/public/assets/manifest.yml /var/www/mrd_production/releases/20150730220743/assets_manifest_backup as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [30408583] Finished in 0.270 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO Uploading /home/drobazko/www/mxad-mr.-delivery/config/database.yml.production 100.0%
INFO [deploy:migrate] Run `rake db:migrate`
INFO [e0eabe3f] Running ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake db:migrate as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [e0eabe3f] Finished in 14.161 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [36cbdf44] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/www/mrd_production/releases/20150730220743 /var/www/mrd_production/releases/current as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [36cbdf44] Finished in 0.270 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [f261e897] Running /usr/bin/env mv /var/www/mrd_production/releases/current /var/www/mrd_production as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [f261e897] Finished in 0.266 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [47336a26] Running /usr/bin/env touch /var/www/mrd_production/releases/20150730220743/tmp/restart.txt as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [47336a26] Finished in 0.267 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO Keeping 3 of 4 deployed releases on <server-ip>
INFO [81cb4cbd] Running /usr/bin/env rm -rf /var/www/mrd_production/releases/20150730162232 as deploy@<server-ip>
INFO [81cb4cbd] Finished in 0.384 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [673ac3d6] Running /usr/bin/env echo "Branch master (at 6ce11b0) deployed as release 20150730220743 by drobazko" >> /var/www/mrd_production/revisions.log as deploy@<server-ip>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, when Capistrano makes the `current` folder it is actually a "shortcut" (for lack of a better term) to the most recent release (perhaps symlinked directory is better).

I don't know of a link to their doc that describes what I'm talking about, but I'm fairly certain that you should be fine with whatever you'd like to run.

EDIT:

[this page](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/structure/) describes the structure of the capistrano directory hierarchy. If you look specifically at the section on `current` it reads:

> **current** is a symlink pointing to the latest release. This symlink is updated at the end of a successful deployment. If the deployment fails in any step the current symlink still points to the old release.
>
> **releases** holds all deployments in a timestamped folder. These folders are the target of the **current** symlink.

Comment: Thanks, for reply. I have added capistrano script log. There is 'ln -s' call. That what did you mean?

Comment: Well what I meant is that `Rails.root` is supposed to return `release` and not `current` because current is like a shortcut folder. Why do you specifically need `current` as the root?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're still in the "old" current symlink after you deployed.  cd out of current then back in, then jump back into the Rails console and you should be in the new correct release path.

This line is showing that the symlinking of current to the latest release directory happened correctly

```
INFO [36cbdf44] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/www/mrd_production/releases/20150730220743 /var/www/mrd_production/releases/current as deploy@<server-ip>
```

You can't stay in current while the deploy happens else the symlink is change out from under you and the shell doesn't know.

Other things of note:

To open a shell like you are in deploy.rb, just use https://github.com/marshall-lee/capistrano-shell.

Additionally don't create shell commands from string concatenation, use the DSL, for example.

```
task :do_something do
  on roles(:web) do
    within release_path do
      with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
        execute :rake, 'simple:task'
      end
    end
  end
end
```